# Unable to install any package by composer in YII2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I am trying to install package library by composer in YII2. But after running the command from my command prompt I am getting following error

My composer command is

```
composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker "*"
```

> Package yiisoft/yii2-codeception is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use codeception/codeception instead.

When installing by this command

```
php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-social "@dev"
```

Then I am getting following error

> Package facebook/php-sdk-v4 is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use facebook/graph-sdk instead.
>
> Generating autoload files

Please suggest me how can I resolve this error

Comment: Please format your code properly in code blocks. I'm not an expert in this area, but you may also need to include some more details about your configuration.

Comment: Can you try with `composer require kartik-v/yii2-social "@dev"`

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. This is just an information for you from composer that one of the required packages has been abandoned and you should not expect to get updates for it.

If you want to get rid of this information simply remove the mentioned packages from the `composer.json` file of your project.
If the package is not listed there it means that one of the required packages listed needs it as dependency so you can not remove it directly.

As for the Yii 2 - here is the [current advanced project template's composer.json](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/composer.json) so you can update the one in your project - package `yiisoft/yii2-codeception` is no longer used.

Comment: If i Will remove it  from composer.json does it create any problem.

Comment: Yes I have removed it from my composer.json and after that I run the command composer.update. Now this file is not inside my composer.json.